# Split list python

Tags: python, list

```
[' -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0 -80.82377033116026,39.83364133601582,0 -80.82356083750963,39.82911201506083,0 -80.82285757569279,39.82686138006091,0']
```

I extracted coordinates from a KML file with 3 polygons and one of the polygon's coordinates are stored in the one element of the list. I want to calculate the min of the longitude and latitude respectively. Does anyone know how to do that?

Do I need to split the list somehow and then proceed?

Very much appreciated!

Comment: You have a list containing one string?

Comment: I was wondering the same, or is that one element from the list?

Comment: Actually I have a list containing three strings. This is just one of them. I think if I can figure out one, I may be able to do the rest by a simple loop. Thanks for your question!

Comment: It's one element from the list. For example, the -80.82581786107986 is longitude, 39.83903198141125 is latitude. and ",0" is something I don't need and it is  contained in a bigger KML string.

Comment: What you displayed here is a list of only one string. Please update with the actual data

Comment: It would be an easy question if only one could understand it clearly. List or string? Which elements are the longitude? Why the `0-`?

Comment: [' -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0 -80.82377033116026,39.83364133601582,0 -80.82356083750963,39.82911201506083,0' '-80.82285757569279,39.82686138006091,0 -80.82211394716366,39.82370641582035,0 -80.82079041778377,39.82101855094219,0',' -80.82008287730855,39.84462640578131,0 -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0']

Comment: The ",0" is something contained in the KML  and is something I want to get rid of. all the -80s are the longitudes, 39s are the latitude. I first parsed these from a bigger KML string and I then want to calculate statistics based on this list. I have three polygons, so I have a list of three elements. I just showed originally one element and I just posted the whole list.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "altitude", perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. **Note**: In Python 2.x

I take the single string, strip the outer whitespace, the split the values on whitespace or commas. That yields this array, which you can loop over in groups to get values.

```
['-80.82581786107986', '39.83903198141125', '0', '-80.82377033116026', '39.83364133601582', '0', '-80.82356083750963', '39.82911201506083', '0', '-80.82285757569279', '39.82686138006091', '0']
```

---

```
import re

l = [' -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0 -80.82377033116026,39.83364133601582,0 -80.82356083750963,39.82911201506083,0',
    '-80.82285757569279,39.82686138006091,0 -80.82211394716366,39.82370641582035,0 -80.82079041778377,39.82101855094219,0',
    ' -80.82008287730855,39.84462640578131,0 -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0']

for s in l: 
    parts = map(float, re.split(r'[,\s+]', s.strip()))

    lats = []
    longs = []

    for i in range(0, len(parts), 3):
        long = parts[i]
        lat = parts[i+1]
        longs.append(long)
        lats.append(lat)

    print min(lats), min(longs)
```

**Output**

```
39.8291120151 -80.8258178611
39.8210185509 -80.8228575757
39.8390319814 -80.8258178611
```

Comment: [' -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0 -80.82377033116026,39.83364133601582,0 -80.82356083750963,39.82911201506083,0' '-80.82285757569279,39.82686138006091,0 -80.82211394716366,39.82370641582035,0 -80.82079041778377,39.82101855094219,0',' -80.82008287730855,39.84462640578131,0 -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0']  My whole list is like this, how can I convert each element to the type of list? Thanks! I am really new to Python!

Comment: I think you want each element of the type `float`, no?

Comment: My question is based on your code, you treat each element as a list: l = [' -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0 -80.82377033116026,39.83364133601582,0 -80.82356083750963,39.82911201506083,0 -80.82285757569279,39.82686138006091,0'] I want to do something like for i in range(0,len(c)): some code for each of the three element. Will that be possible?

Comment: Thanks so much. The only problem is I have three elements. So how to get the min stats for each of the three elements?

Comment: Thanks so much! That is exactly what I want! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome. I do think that the numpy answer is more extensible, but that requires installing and using numpy, which I wouldn't dump on someone new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
>>> my_list = [' -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0 -80.82377033116026,39.83364133601582,0 -80.82356083750963,39.82911201506083,0 -80.82285757569279,39.82686138006091,0']
>>> map(lambda x: map(float, x.split(",")), my_list[0].strip().split())
[[-80.82581786107986, 39.83903198141125, 0.0], [-80.82377033116026, 39.83364133601582, 0.0], [-80.82356083750963, 39.82911201506083, 0.0], [-80.8228575756928, 39.82686138006091, 0.0]]
```

Mean of latitude and longitude:

```
>>> map(lambda x: (x[0]+x[1])/2, map(lambda x: map(float, x.split(",")), my_list[0].strip().split()))
[-20.4933929398343, -20.49506449757222, -20.4972244112244, -20.49799809781594]
```

you can use pandas too:

```
>>> import `pandas` as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(map(lambda x: map(float, x.split(",")), my_list[0].strip().split()))
           0          1  2
0 -80.825818  39.839032  0
1 -80.823770  39.833641  0
2 -80.823561  39.829112  0
3 -80.822858  39.826861  0
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(map(lambda x: map(float, x.split(",")), my_list[0].strip().split()))
>>> data.mean()
0   -80.824002
1    39.832162
2     0.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think you missed the part of the question that said "I want to calculate the min of the longitude and latitude respectively"

Comment: Thanks, but a element of the list is a string, will your code still work? I have three elements in the list. I want to do one and will loop to do the rest. Thanks for your help!

Comment: averaging a latitude and a longitude value doesn't make any sense... also not what OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehension`, `str.split()` and `str.strip` methods:

```
l = [' -80.82581786107986,39.83903198141125,0 -80.82377033116026,39.83364133601582,0 -80.82356083750963,39.82911201506083,0 -80.82285757569279,39.82686138006091,0']
res = [list(map(float, coord.split(','))) for coord in l[0].strip().split()]

In [217]: res 
Out[217]:
[[-80.82581786107986, 39.83903198141125, 0.0],
 [-80.82377033116026, 39.83364133601582, 0.0],
 [-80.82356083750963, 39.82911201506083, 0.0],
 [-80.8228575756928, 39.82686138006091, 0.0]]
```

To calculate the min and longtitude and latitude you could convert that list to `np.array` for easy manipulation and use `ndarray` method [`min`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjTxc_5yuzKAhXsZpoKHRZXCgwQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.1%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.ndarray.min.html&usg=AFQjCNFJqVdzKvJ2eW8nRzUiJG-RCsbDng&bvm=bv.113943665,d.bGs) with `axis=0` or [`np.amin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(res)

In [221]: arr
Out[221]:
array([[-80.82581786,  39.83903198,   0.        ],
       [-80.82377033,  39.83364134,   0.        ],
       [-80.82356084,  39.82911202,   0.        ],
       [-80.82285758,  39.82686138,   0.        ]])

In [224]: arr.min(axis=0)
Out[224]: array([-80.82581786,  39.82686138,   0.        ])

In [226]: np.amin(arr, axis=0)
Out[226]: array([-80.82581786,  39.82686138,   0.        ])
```

Comment: Thanks, but a element of the list is a string, will your code still work? I have three elements in the list. I want to do one and will loop to do the rest. Thanks for your help! I am really new to Python! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @tomtomxu if you'll check the solution you could find that it used `map` with `float` which means convert `str` to `float`.